# (React) Cannnot read property 'maps' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api

When I use API, I get a message: Cannnot read property 'maps' of undefined.
I know this is a problem that I failed at giving a first data.
But I'm not sure how can I solve this problem.
(And actually I tried this way: write [] at the last of the code.)
Can anybody kindly told me how can I fix this? Thank you.
Whole code is at the bottom.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
const Restaurant_result = () => {

  const { kakao } = window;

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName('myMap');
    const options = {
    center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(33.450701, 126.570667),
    level: 3
    };
    const map = new kakao.maps.Map(container, options);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='myMap'/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Restaurant_result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The element 'kakao' is not part of your window object, thus it is undefined and doesn't have a 'maps' element.

Comment: Because of that, I add "const { kakao } = window;" at my code. But it doesn't work... Thank you for your advice.